# How to set android lock screen image from the app through coding

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm just getting started with android programming, and i have created this app called "Awesome Quotes" which shows images. I don't know if that is possible or not but i want to show images from my app to show as lockscreen background image.but surely there must be a way to set the image programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the Service and receiver from this project:

https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp